# jsp get previous form value

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have 2 servlet 1 html page and 1 jsp page.
Now I want to get the previous form value into new page.

Eg. test.html have a input form, then i type something on it. Then, submit. output2.jsp page come out. output2.jsp is same with test.html, have a input form. Then, i submit again without type anything in output2.jsp. It come back to output2.jsp page, but now it contain text in the input form where the text is the text that i type in test.html. Can it be done?

Example flow: test.html (type something) -> servlet1 -> output2.jsp (not type anything) -> servlet2 -> output2.jsp (input form contain test.html value that i type)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done thru passing form values to servlet1 and servlet forward that request to ouput2.jsp and then it again forwards to servlet2. Servlet 2 again can forward this message this to ouptut2.jsp.

But here there is an issue. this will go to infinite loop if you don't add a logic saying that request is coming servlet1 or servlet2 in output2.jsp

Comment: Can it be done, if i not forward request to output2.jsp from servlet1?

Answer (score 0):

Fowarding the input typed in *test.html* to *output2.jsp* in ***servlet1*** as:

```
request.setAttribute("reqAttr1", typedText);
```

In ***servlet2***, get the attribute from request and set the value to the form element.